# what do we need to pass in json input to add bundle product into cart using magento 2 rest api

Tags: rest, magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8

I want to add bundle product into cart using REST API

**POST**: `http://localhost/magento/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items`

**input**:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "Bundle Product",
    "qty": 4,
    "quote_id": "29"
  }
}
```

but I am getting one error from magento:
"Warning: **Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/CartItemProcessor.php on line 87"**

Add to cart with simple product is working:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "Simple Product",
    "qty": 4,
    "quote_id": "29"
  }
}
```

Please help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution.
It is based on Magento2 (I see different tags, but I think, according to the error message, that you want it for Magento2).

Let's assume that our bundle is identified by the SKU "bundle01" and ID *123*.

First of all, let's take some information from the product:

`GET /products/bundle01?searchCriteria`

and take note of the `"extension_attributes" --> "bundle_product_options"` section, particularly to the `option_id`fields related to your products. And take not of all the `product_links` --> `id` values related to the product.

Let's assume that we have 3 products with option_id 643, 644, 645 and id 704,705,706 respectively.

With all these information, here's the body to add a bundle product to your cart:

```
{
"cart_item": {
    "quote_id": <quote_id>,
    "sku": "bundle-01",
    "qty": 1,
    "product_option": {
    "extension_attributes": {
        "bundle_options": [{
            "option_id": 643,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [704]
            }, {
            "option_id": 644,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [705]
            }, {
            "option_id": 645,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [706]
            }]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Are the option_selections supposed to be the product_ids? Also, what if I have > 1 product in an option set and they have different quantities? Should I add 2 entries to the bundle_options array, 1 for each quantity? 

Currently I'm getting back the following message: "The options you selected are not available."

Any help would be much appreciated. I wish their docs talked about this more in depth.